# How to through a java application to transfer data to the servlet

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a java application sent a string that is a json,it isn't get this json in servlet, how do I do, who can help me?
This is my servlet code:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(req.getInputStream());
    byte[] data = null;
    byte[] bts = new byte[1024];
    int index;
    while ((index = in.read(bts)) >= 0) {
        if (data == null) {
            data = new byte[index];
            System.arraycopy(bts, 0, data, 0, index);
        }
        else {
            byte[] tmp = data;
            data = new byte[tmp.length + index];
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, data, 0, tmp.length);
            System.arraycopy(bts, 0, data, tmp.length, index);
        }
    }
    String json = new String(data);
            System.out.print(json);
}
```

and this is my java application:

```
String _url = "http://localhost:8080/jsf/test";
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlconn = null;
    String json = URLEncoder.encode(JSONObject.fromObject(req)
            .toString(), "UTF-8");
    url = new URL(_url);
    urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlconn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlconn.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStream out = urlconn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            urlconn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = rd.read()) > -1) {
        sb.append((char) ch);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    rd.close();
```

Comment: Your code never sends the JSON. Send it to the connection's output stream, then tell you precisely what happens.

Comment: I hava tried output stream like thisOutputStream out = urlconn.getOutputStream();
   out.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   out.flush();
   out.close();but is not work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a very poor description of the problem. What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? If you get an exception, what's the stack trace? When you go to the doctor, you don't just say "I'm sick, it hurts". You describe the symptoms, what you feel, where. Same here.

Comment: I mean, I did not find a way to get this json in my servlet

Comment: So, you mean that the problem you have is that you don't know how to get the JSON in the servlet? Then why don't ask that, clearly, and why don't you show the servlet code instead of the client code? Is the servlet invoked? Do you have debugging traces in the servlet?

Comment: I modified my question, I hope I clearly described, in fact, my English is not very good

Answer (score 0):

You should write json data to outputStream as out.write(json.getBytes()); . See the complete code below:

```
String _url = "http://localhost:8080/jsf/test";
URL url = new URL(_url);
String json = "[{\"id\":\"DFAB8108D69642EBBD461160B4519B0F\",\"name\":\"name1\"},{\"id\":\"B048B2521A5619DCE0440003BA11CFDA\",\"name\":\"name2\"}]";
HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlconn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream out = urlconn.getOutputStream();
out.write(json.getBytes());
out.flush();
out.close();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        urlconn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int ch;
while ((ch = rd.read()) > -1) {
    sb.append((char) ch);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
rd.close();
```

Comment: Though here okay, better `json.getBytes("UTF-8")`. `flush` not needed. `StringBuilder` i.o. `StringBuffer` - even though the question used these.

Comment: @lee tan, did you try the given solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
String _url = "http://localhost:8080/jsf/test";
URL url = new URL(_url);
String json = "[{\"id\":\"DFAB8108D69642EBBD461160B4519B0F\",\"name\":\"name1\"},{\"id\":\"B048B2521A5619DCE0440003BA11CFDA\",\"name\":\"name2\"}]";
HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlconn .setDoOutput(true);
    urlconn .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    urlconn .setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlconn .setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlconn .connect();

    OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
    os.write((json.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    os.close();
```